# Storing Ipv4 address into a .env variable

Tags: batch-file, cmd, environment-variables, mern

I am trying to find a way on how to store a IPV4 address into a variable in .ENV file in my ReactJS project, but my problems are:

1.) How can I get the IPV4 address by using either a batch file or an environmental file?

2.) If I am using a Batch file, how can I write the IPV4 address, that I have gotten, into the .env file?

**Why am I trying to do this?**

I have been creating a MERN app, and this works only in a LAN network. To access this web application I need to use my device's IP address as the hostname of the URL, but the problem is, whenever I connect to my Wifi my IPv4 changes, and I think it is too hassle to change it over and over again as my IPv4 changes.

If you guys have any idea please feel free to share it with me :) Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: I would suggest a [for /f](https://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) loop to capture the IP address from an appropriate command. The method you use would depend on your version of Windows. You can use [netsh](https://ss64.com/nt/netsh.html), [ipconfig](https://ss64.com/nt/ipconfig.html) and [wmic nicconfig](https://ss64.com/nt/wmic.html).

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple of examples of ways you could do this:

```
for /f "tokens=3" %%g in ('%__APPDIR__%netsh.exe interface ipv4 show config "Wi-Fi" ^|findstr "IP Address"') do set "_IPAddress=%%g"
```

Replace "Wi-Fi" with the name of your interface.

```
for /f "tokens=2 delims={;" %%g in ('%__APPDIR__%wbem\WMIC.exe nicconfig where "IPEnabled='TRUE'" get IPAddress /format:csv') do set "_IPAddress=%%g"
```

This one requires wmic to be installed, which may not be the case with Windows 11.

Once you have set the IP Address to a variable, you can use it like `echo %_IPAddress%.`